# How to assign whether a specific date is during work hours or not. (SPSS)

Tags: date, spss

Hi i'm new to this site so forgive me if i didn't search for this question thoroughly enough!

Basically i'm doing a research project where one of the variables is whether an xray was performed during normal work hours or not. Work hours include Monday-Friday, 8am-5pm.

I have input the date and time of each xray using separate variables 
-[date+time (dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm)] 
-[time (hh:mm)].

I was planning on inputing this information manually but i though that surely there is way to automate this and since i have next to zero experience with SPSS i thought i should ask you lovely people to help me out!

Thankyou in advance

Comment: I'm confused what your question is. What current format is the data in now and what format do you want it to be in?

Comment: Sorry i probably didn't explain myself very well. I'm manually inputing raw data from xray reports on infants. Basically i input the time and date that the xray was performed as a variable using 'date' as the type of variable. What i need is to find out whether that date was a sat or sunday and if it is before 8am or after 5pm. I could do this manually quite easily but i have about 6000 cases so its not really feasible. Im not even sure if spss can do this sort of thing but i just thought i would check.

Comment: Thanks, that is much clearer! I might be able to write up an example sometime tomorrow, but for now you want to look up the [XDATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_date_and_time_extraction_functions.htm) functions. They help to extract the specific needed data-time info from each record, and then one can just make if statements to identify the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I go through a quick example utilizing the xdate function to extract the day of week, and then construction an if statement to identify whether these date-times fall within `workhours`.

```
*Making example data.
data list free / xray_date (ADATE10) xray_time (TIME5).
begin data
7/6/2011 2:21
10/11/2011 15:42
07/06/2011 02:21
3/15/2011 0:21
end data.

*Here is example to find day of week name, 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday.
compute day_week = Xdate.Wkday(xray_date).

*to identify times of day in an if statement we need to make specific variables.
string begin_time end_time (A5).
compute begin_time = "08:00".
compute end_time = "17:00".
alter type begin_time end_time (TIME5).

*Then you can just make an if statement to identify whether a date-time meets your requirements.
compute workhours = 0.
if day_week >= 2 and day_week <= 6 and xray_time >= begin_time and xray_time <= end_time workhours = 1.
```

For this particular example, if you run the command `list all.` the resulting output will be;

```
 xray_date xray_time day_week begin_time end_time workhours 

07/06/2011    2:21    4.00000     8:00     17:00     .00000 
10/11/2011   15:42    3.00000     8:00     17:00    1.00000 
07/06/2011    2:21    4.00000     8:00     17:00     .00000 
03/15/2011    0:21    3.00000     8:00     17:00     .00000
```

You can see the record with `10/11/2011` was appropriately classified as it is a Tuesday and within working hours. All of the other records are not between 8 am and 5 pm, so are initialized to the zero value for the `workhours` variable.